# MySQL query does not include return todays purchase

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this MySQL query that works fine in most cases, except that if there is a purchase "today", this latest data is not included in the $result. Even though it is covered within the date range($date_start and $data_end).

```
   $units_sold=intval($wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("
    SELECT COUNT(id) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}my_affiliate
    WHERE timestamp
    BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(%s) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(%s)
    AND user_id=%d
    AND description=%s
    ",
    $date_start,$date_end,$user_id,$product_type
)));
```

Any suggestions to make the above query as accurate as possible,would be highly appreciated. I have tried adding one day or something like that, but still confused on getting the most reliable/accurate query in doing this. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: My suggestion would be to move away from using `between` and build two seperate clauses (timestamp>= and timestamp<=) to help ensure the logic is consistent with what you're expecting.

Comment: So what value do you have for `$date_end`?

Comment: Why dont you replace date_end with NOW?

Comment: $date_end is the date for today..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming $date_end contains a date? Instead, use a full timestamp. (Otherwise it will include all purchase up to today: 01/dec/2013 0:00:00) or add one day to the end date.

Consider using now() instead for the interval that should include today